# Border table in PHP and layout print

Tags: php, html-table, ms-word, border

I have two issues with the results page of a query ....
issue number 1
border of a table.

I have a string of equal strings to this one

```
$ content. = "<tr> <td> Total <td>". $ line ["total"]. "";
```

I just want to have the border to the variable php (`". $ riga [" total"]."`).

I tried with
PHP: `$ content. = "<tr> <td> Total <td> <table border =" 1 ">". $ line ["total_arrest"]. "";`
, but obviously goes wrong.

how can I fix it?

issue number 2

export result search in word with this code

```
if (isset ($ _ POST ['submit'])) {
       header ("Content-Type: application / vnd.msword");
       header ("Expires: 0"); // no-cache
      header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check = 0, pre-check = 0"); // no-cache
    header ("content-disposition: attachment; filename = morning _" date ("d_m_Y"). "doc");
```

}

I export it correctly but I would like to export it with print layout because it does it in web layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Issue number 1 you can try Inline CSS styling in your table tag i.e.

style ="border: 1px solid black;"

Comment: the table is divided into two fields ... total that is html and the php variable, "$ line [" total "]." ";

the border should only be highlighted on the variable

Comment: then do the css styling inside the `td` tag. i.e. `$ content. = "<tr> <td style ='border: 1px solid black;'> Total <td>". $ line ["total"]. "";`